# Copy with sed 's//'

Tags: c, regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a file with various 'return BBQ;' statements. I'd like to change them all to 'exit(BBQ);\nreturn BBQ;' (with BBQ being an arbitrary value). Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backreferences.

```
s/return \(BBQ\);/exit(\1);\nreturn \1;/
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Now, can I make this work for any value? (e.g. 'return *;')

Comment: This is not called a backreference but a subexpression match or something similar. Backreferences are a non-regular extension to "regular expressions" which make "regex" matching insanely slow.

Comment: @R.. - POSIX actually does refer to these as back-references: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03_07 (and subexpressions)